# Block Outgoing SMS in Android

Tags: android, sms

I am making an android application that could filter the recipient name and number while composing a message (with Native SMS APP). Please help me how can i filter the contact details with my application running in background.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, short of creating your own ROM mod with a replaced `ContactsContract` provider that implements your "filter". You did not write the "Native SMS APP", you did not write `ContactsContract`, and you did not write the operating system, and so you have no means to interfere with their inter-communication.